# Updating a dynamically created ImageView with Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying to do something I think is simple, but just having a few issues on iOS using Titanium 5.2.2 SDK.

So, I have an app that pulls down a list of Employees from a JSON file hosted outside the app, I cache all that data in an onboard DB and create a masked Image for each employee inside my loop.

```
employeeImage[i] = Titanium.UI.createMaskedImage({
                        mask : employee_image, // background image
                        tint: 'black',
                        mode : Titanium.UI.iOS.BLEND_MODE_COLOR,
                        width: 210,
                        height: 210,
                        touchEnabled: false,
                        custom_employee_id: employee_id
                    });
```

I need to be able to refer to that Image and update the tint from 'black' to something 'else' elsewhere in my app, so I'm not having to do constant look ups and refreshing every single image.

I want to do something like this:

```
// get the employee status
            var db = Ti.Database.open('Enter');
            var getEmp = db.execute('SELECT employee_id, employee_status FROM Employee');
                while (getEmp.isValidRow())
                {
                  var empID = getEmp.fieldByName('employee_id');
                  var empStatus = getEmp.fieldByName('employee_status');
                  Ti.API.info(empID + ' ' + empStatus);

                  // update the images correctly
                  if (empStatus == 0) {
                    // update the image mask to black if they are now out of the building
                    Ti.API.info('Status is zero');
                    //employeeImage[i].tint = 'black';
                  } else {
                    // update the image mask to transparent if they are now in the building
                    Ti.API.info('Status is ONE');
                    //employeeImage[i].tint = 'transparent';
                  }


                  getEmp.next();
                }
                getEmp.close();

                db.close();
```

The problem is, I don't know if I can set those changes to the image view if it has a dynamic name.

If it were just called employeeImage1 this would be easy. However, if I try call employeeImage1 instead of employeeImage[i] I get this error.

**"Can't find variable: employeeImage1";**

How do I get around this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no doubt that you can store your objects as array elements.  I've reduced your sample to the following testcase:

```
(function(){
    var count=10;
    var i=0;
    var employeeImage=[];
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        employeeImage[i]=Ti.UI.createButton({
            title : "Employee " + i
        });
    }
    for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
      console.log(employeeImage[i].title);
    }
})()
```

The output for this is what you'd expect:

```
[INFO]  Employee 0
[INFO]  Employee 1
[INFO]  Employee 2
[INFO]  Employee 3
[INFO]  Employee 4    
[INFO]  Employee 5
[INFO]  Employee 6
[INFO]  Employee 7
[INFO]  Employee 8
[INFO]  Employee 9
```

Now, as array elements, you should call it as employeeImage[n] and not as employeeImageN, because employeeImageN doesn't exists, what exists is a reference to your object stored as array elements.

Does this make sense.

R

Comment: I think so, sadly not got my code with me to try but I'll give it a whirl first thing tomorrow. Thanks for taking the time to explain!

Comment: I actually have the masked images already created inside a loop, like in your example. for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) { etc etc. That all works fine, it's just the bit where calling it back in as employeeImage[i] doesn't work

Comment: for easiness I've pasted my entire code into here http://pastebin.com/n46izkLT so it is easy to see what I am doing. The issue lies with lines 178 and 182. I suspect it is because it outside the other function that creates the array. Any ideas?

Comment: Here are some observations - I can't run your code because it uses database calls, so these are based on reading your code.

The employeeImage in lines 178 and 182 is in the scope of the loader.onload callback.  However you fill out the values in the scope of loadData().  So my hypothesis is that you're using two different instances of the same variable in different scopes.  If this is true, then you'll need to refactor your code so you can pass around the array so you're using a single copy throughout.

Again, this is a hypothesis based on reading your code.  Hope it helps.

Comment: OK, not wanting to sound like a complete novice here, in simple terms, how would I be able to pass the array around easily? Being able to jump between functions ideally!

Comment: The right way is turning your code into CommonJS libraries.  The easy, though not so appropriate hack would be to remove 254, and bring 234 all the way to the top of the file, so the array actually becomes global to all subsequent uses.

Comment: Awesome! Taking it out to the top worked, thanks so much!

Comment: Great to hear.  I recommend going the re-factoring route.  You've effectively created a global variable and it could potentially leak memory.  

The issues we've discussed here are by the way JavaScript issues and not Titanium, so you should be able to find ideas on how to re-factor it by looking at plain-vanilla JavaScript code.

Comment: That's ok, this is just a proof of concept app at the moment, will definitely sort it out to be more memory friendly before real world deployment. Thanks again for taking the time to help Ricardo